# Change color every second of a wix text box element

Tags: javascript, java, velo

I tried to use the code below to change text color to random colors every second but it didn't work, and it's giving and error 'tx.style is undefined'. The same code worked in atom text editor. why?

```
const tx = $w('#text16');

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function changeColor(){
  tx.style.color= getRandomColor();
}

setInterval(changeColor,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Velo, the text element does not have a `style` property. The only way to currently change the text color is to set the text using the `html` property and adding inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one - make sure your original html matches, though.

```
const changeColor = (element, color) => {
    if (element.type !== '$w.Text') {
        return;
    }

    const { html } = element;
    const newHtml = html.indexOf('color:') > -1 
        ? html.replace(/color:\s{0,2}[^ ;"']+/g, `color: ${color}`)
        : html.replace(/style="/g, `style="color: ${color}; `);

    element.html = newHtml;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your error is in how you find your element.
You could try console.log(tx) and see what you get.

Seems to work:

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box")

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function changeColor(){
  box.style.color = getRandomColor();
}

setInterval(changeColor,1000);
```

```html
<div id="box">
Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: Element is exactly what the problem is. I need to know how to refer to the text box element's text color inside a function.

Comment: The question is referring to Velo by Wix, where you cannot select elements using getElementById.